# Database does not open (Java program via DIIOP)

Tags: java, eclipse, lotus-domino

I try to open a database on a Domino server via a java program. 
Got a session to the Domino server. I use the following code to get/open the database.

```
session = NotesFactory.createSession(DOMINO_SERVER, DOMINO_USER, DOMINO_PW);
if ( session == null ) {
//do something
}
db = session.getDatabase(DOMINO_SERVER, DOMINO_DATABASE);
view = db.getView("someView");
```

The following error message occurs:

NotesException: Database xyz has not been opened yet

If I use the "open" - method

```
db.open();
```

the error

NotesException: Database open() failed

occurs.
User has access to database. Maximum Internet name and password: READER.

Are there any configurations on the domino server I can check?
Seems to be an security problem, but I don't see the cause.
Any suggestions/hints?

**[Update]**
Complete stack trace ...

```
NotesException: Database XYZ has not been opened yet
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHelper.read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHolder._read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.corba._IDatabaseStub.getSize(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Database.getSize(Unknown Source)
```

For testing I try to get the size of the database with the "getSize()" method.

Complete stack trace from other error message:

```
NotesException: Database open failed ()
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHelper.read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHolder._read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.corba._IDatabaseStub.open(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Database.open(Unknown Source)
```

**[Update 2]:**
Screenshot from server console:

[image: Screenshot from server console]

Comment: What version of Domino are you using (and what fix pack if any)? This is a follow on from your other question. Any joy creating DIIOP debug logs?

Comment: Domino server version: Release 8.5.3FP4
Yes Simon it's a follow from my other question. The DIIOP debug logs are not very helpful. It prints out a lot but no new helpful error messages. Do you look for someting specific? Can I send you more details?

Comment: If you can post the logs I can read them, but I have nothing I can point you to which will explain in detail.

Comment: Debug parameter only prints results on live console. Can't find the entries in the log.nsf. Can't post a screenshot ... need 10 reputations to post, wtf?

Comment: I upvoted you, so you now have 11 reputation points.  Can you try re-pointing your code to a different test database? I would recommend first testing with a database that has -Default- = Manager & Anonymous = Manager & Maximum Internet access = Manager. Let's make sure that opens. Then change Anonymous to No Access, see what happens. Assuming that works, then we know you are authenticating okay, and have no server access probklems. Then make one ACL change at a time until it matches the config of the real database - including max internet access setting. See what happens.

Comment: Anonymous TCP access is not allowed for the server. Setting Default - Manager and Maximum internet access - Manager triggers the same error message (Database open failed!).

Comment: Setting user access rights to Manager and Maximum internet access - Manager triggers the error message (Database open failed!) too.

Comment: CONSOLE_LOG_ENABLED=1 and the logs should appear in your IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT Folder. Getting my glasses! :D

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the notes.ini param. So I know for the future  ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question answered.

Comment: Just to finish on this. There is more granular debug to help determine the root cause, but would require opening a PMR, as the logs are verbose and meaningless outside the context of development (So wouldn't help posted on SO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem with idea above from Simon.

I tried an other method to open the database.
Here the way I tried to open the database.

```
session = NotesFactory.createSession(DOMINO_SERVER, DOMINO_USER, DOMINO_PW);
if ( session == null ) {
//do something
}
DbDirectory dir = session.getDbDirectory(null);
db = dir.openDatabase(DOMINO_DATABASE);
```

Nothing changed on the access rights for the user to server and database.
Not sure why it works this way? Is there a bug or is there something with the server configuration?

But most important ... it works now ... thanks Simon and Richard.

Answer (score 1):

OK based on the logs, can you check that you do not have the Notes.jar on the CLASSPATH, only NCSO.jar.

Also can you try other methods to open the same database, and post the logs if the issue reoccurs.

Example:

```
Dim db As New NotesDatabase( "", "" )
Call db.Open( "server", "names.nsf" )
```

Comment: Checked the jar-Files. Only the NCSO.jar from the server is in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Based on the other commands working, this does ring a bell. I will see if I can find more details.